School Enrollment System for School
I am developing a Website for School. where students can enroll in courses, and there are compulsory and elective subjects. So I want when users fill out the Enrollment form, they need to register first, then enter personal and parental information, choose a grade, choose electives, and make the payment, and then see an invoice.
Please guide me Which plugin/method can help me to achieve my requirement.

A custom plugin can be developed to provide specific functionality not offered by existing plugins. This ensures the solution is tailored to your requirements and allows for easy modifications and future enhancements.
